# Cannot get data to bind and display - Windows Phone 8 longlist selector and XML

Tags: xml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have looked all through MSDN and StackEchange and elsewhere but can't seem to find that magical missing step to my problem. I am loading some XML data (timetable information) using the following code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Resources;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using XML_Long_List.Resources;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace XML_Long_List
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        XElement loadedXEL;
        Collection<timetable> timetable1;

        StreamResourceInfo xml = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("XMLData/tt.xml", UriKind.Relative));
        loadedXEL = XElement.Load(xml.Stream);

        //retriving data from xml using LINQ
        var dataset = from query in loadedXEL.Descendants("record")
                      select new timetable
                      {
                          uniqueID = query.Element("uniqueid").Value,
                          departTime = query.Element("departtime").Value,
                          departAMPM = query.Element("departampm").Value
                      };
        timetable1 = new Collection<timetable>();
        foreach (timetable ttentry in dataset)
        {
            timetable1.Add(ttentry);
        }
        timelist.DataContext = timetable1;
        timelist.ItemsSource = dataset.ToList();

        /*
        foreach (var entryitem in timetable1)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entryitem.uniqueID))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NULL OR EMPTY");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(entryitem.uniqueID);
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entryitem.departTime))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NULL OR EMPTY");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(entryitem.departTime);
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entryitem.departAMPM))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NULL OR EMPTY");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(entryitem.departAMPM);
            }
        }
        */

    }
}

public class timetable
{
    private string _uniqueID;
    private string _departTime;
    private string _departAMPM;

    public string uniqueID { get { return _uniqueID; } set { _uniqueID = value; } }
    public string departTime { get { return _departTime; } set { _departTime = value; } }
    public string departAMPM { get { return _departAMPM; } set { _departAMPM = value; } }
}
}
```

And the XAML is:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XML_Long_List"
x:Class="XML_Long_List.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="LongListSelectorControlTemplate1" TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,275">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="14*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="15*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="51*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="101*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding departAMPM}" Foreground="White">
                <TextBlock.DataContext>
                    <local:timetable/>
                </TextBlock.DataContext>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding departTime}"/>
            <Button Content="{Binding uniqueID}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="90" Width="153"/>
            <Button Content="{Binding departAMPM}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="90" Width="303"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="timelist" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="449" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" Template="{StaticResource LongListSelectorControlTemplate1}">
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>

</Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Sorry if my code formatting is not great - haven't posted much on here.

The XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<meadinkent>
<record>
<uniqueid>1 </uniqueid>
<departtime>30 Dec 99</departtime>
<departampm>am</departampm>
<arrivetime>30 Dec 99</arrivetime>
<arriveampm>am</arriveampm>
</record>
<record>
<uniqueid>2 </uniqueid>
<departtime>30 Dec 99</departtime>
<departampm>am</departampm>
<arrivetime>30 Dec 99</arrivetime>
<arriveampm>am</arriveampm>
</record>
</record>
</meadinkent>
```

There are actually more records but all the same format.

The data is definitely loaded correctly from the XML file as I can display it using the commented out code. Whatever I try, however, I can't get it to populate the LongListSelector and display on the screen.

What am I missing here?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, really for what I can see at first sight, you are using timeable1 collection in your commented out code, the one that you say works. 
I think you won't need the

```
timelist.DataContext = timetable1;
```

line of code, comment that out and set the next line this way:

```
timelist.ItemsSource = timeable1;
```

If you are trying to show a simple list, and not a grouped list, you can set you longlistselector.itemsource property with a collection. 
Everything looks pretty good on your xaml file.

Hope that helps.